# Select from table removing similar rows - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window, distinct, aggregate-functions

There is a table with document revisions and authors. Looks like this:

```
doc_id    rev_id   rev_date            editor    title,content so on....
123        1       2016-01-01 03:20    Bill        ......
123        2       2016-01-01 03:40    Bill
123        3       2016-01-01 03:50    Bill
123        4       2016-01-01 04:10    Bill
123        5       2016-01-01 08:40    Alice
123        6       2016-01-01 08:41    Alice
123        7       2016-01-01 09:00    Bill
123        8       2016-01-01 10:40    Cate
942        9       2016-01-01 11:10    Alice
942       10       2016-01-01 11:15    Bill
942       15       2016-01-01 11:17    Bill
```

I need to find out moments when document was transferred to another editor - only first rows of every edition series.

Like so:

```
doc_id    rev_id   rev_date            editor    title,content so on....
123        1       2016-01-01 03:20    Bill        ......
123        5       2016-01-01 08:40    Alice
123        7       2016-01-01 09:00    Bill
123        8       2016-01-01 10:40    Cate
942        9       2016-01-01 11:10    Alice
942       10       2016-01-01 11:15    Bill
```

If I use DISTINCT ON (doc_id, editor) it resorts a table and I see only one per doc and editor, that is incorrect.
Of course I can dump all and filter with shell tools like awk | sort | uniq. But it is not good for big tables.

Window functions like FIRST_ROW do not give much, because I cannot partition by doc_id, editor not to mess all them.

How to do better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the previous value, and then a simple comparison:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(editor) over (partition by doc_id order by rev_date) as prev_editor
      from t
     ) t
where prev_editor is null or prev_editor <> editor;
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.